# Deployment to a different enviroment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

New SSRS user and have just worked through my first training book (Kathi Kellenberger) and have a question before I move out of Adventure works and to our environment.

I will be creating reports in a test environment.  This means that my datasets (and shared datasets) will be aimed a the test server.  Once the report is published and approved by the users, is there a way to automatically copy the report from test to production?

If not, then can you confirm that I would need to copy the report from test to production and then change the dataset properties to point to the correct server.

Thank you in advance for the newbie help!

Comment: All you should need to do is change the Data Source to production data and apply any necessary credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your production environment is on another server, then create a new project in your existing solution with deployment configuration set to the production settings. When you are ready to move to production, you can move the RDL in your test project to your production project and click 'deploy' from there.

If they are on the same server, then I would just move it via report manager and change the data source in there as well.